# Complex query from MySQL with GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for a way to SELECT this result:

```
id_item     name1       name2       name3
1           value10     value20     value30
2           -           value40     -
3           value50     value60     -
```

From this DB table (here's custom fields to each id_item):

```
id_item     Name    Value
1           name1   value10
1           name2   value20
1           name3   value30
2           name2   value40
3           name1   value50
3           name2   value60
```

Can't solve it. Is there a way?

Comment: it confused check your table data and result data

Comment: Your id_item values in the result table make no sense. Please correct it.

Comment: Why is group_concat in the title ? There is no relation with the question.

Comment: I have to GROUP_CONCAT the table by id_item. There is a fiew custom fields (Name) to each id_item with various values to each id_item. In my example, id_item=1 has fields "name1", "name2", "name3. id_item=2 has only one field - "name2". etc

Comment: @LorenzMeyer sorry, there really were a mistake. i've corrected it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your new result with this query:

```
SELECT
    id_item,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'name1' THEN value ELSE '-' END) name1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'name2' THEN value ELSE '-' END) name2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'name3' THEN value ELSE '-' END) name3
FROM
    your_table
GROUP BY
    id_item;
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dca46/1)

I adapted this [great answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24636/product-attribute-list-design-pattern#answer-24941) of bluefeet to generate this query dynamically:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
      'MAX(CASE WHEN e.Name = ''',
      e.Name,
      ''' THEN value ELSE ''-'' END) AS ',
      e.Name
    ) INTO @sql
FROM example e;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT e.id_item
                    , ', @sql, ' 
                   from example e
                   GROUP BY e.id_item;');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3c8b4/3)

Comment: Was writing an answer with multiple left joins, this way is much sweeter.

Comment: Using this solution, i have to query fields names previously (name1, name2, name3 - because the may change dinamically). Which is not a big problem, but may be there is a way to solve the issue without substitution field names to the query?

Answer (score 0):

I think You will need to develop store procedure.

Step 1 :  find distinct value of 'Name' Column and store in any session variable

Step 2: use while loop and generate dynamic query

Example:

```
select * from (select A.id_item,if(A.Name='name1',A.Value,Null) as  'name1',if(A.Name='name2',A.Value,Null) as  'name2',if(A.Name='name3',A.Value,Null) as  'name3' from testtable A) group by id_item
```

I hope you get my explanation

If you have any query then comment here then I can build example in sql fiddle if needed.